# Can i make all traffic from a remote router flow through my network?

Tags: remote

My sister is moving out soon.
But I want to make sure she will always be able to connect to the local nas and rdp's.
I dont want her to have to connect via VPN all the time.
Is there any way to do this (or is it a really bad practise to do so?).

Comment: Questions about home networking should be asked on [su].  But briefly, without some authentication method (like a VPN), it's a terrible idea.

Comment: Your question title asks for literally what a VPN does. Why do you want to avoid the VPN?